# jenkins pipeline. curl get works but post doesn't

Tags: windows, jenkins, curl, cmd

I'm running Jenkins pipeline job on a windows 10 agent.
i'm trying to publish some information from the agent to confluence.
Running with script.bat:

```
curl --fail --silent --show-error -u ****:**** -X GET   <SomeInternalAddress>
```

works!

but running:

```
curl --fail --silent --show-error -u ****:**** -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '@tmpCurlPostData.txt' <SomeInternalAddress>
```

results with:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
>
> curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 415

tried escape a '=' in the password with '^'. tried surrounding with quotes.
but with no success.

interesting fact, the same code works fine on win 7,
testing it on a new win 10 machine revealed the problem.
would appreciate any idea guys.
thanks a lot!

Comment: The character `'` has no special meaning for Windows command processor `cmd.exe` while it has a special meaning for Linux shell interpreters. For that reason I suggest to use `"Content-Type: application/json"` and `"@tmpCurlPostData.txt"` which makes hopefully the important difference to get the command line working. The password string should be definitely enclosed in double quotes as otherwise space and these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<|>`` are interpreted by `cmd.exe` not as literal characters of an argument string.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for the response. same code should run on win10 and on linux. so in linux i should use single quotes and for windows use double quotes?

Comment: It is also possible to use `"` instead of `'` in this case on Linux. Please read for example [Linux Shell Script Tutorial - Quoting](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Quoting) to get knowledge about the difference on quoting an argument string with `'` in comparison to `"` in a Linux shell script.